# Let $X$ be normal random variable with $P(X>15)$ and $\sigma^{2}=4$. find $\mu$

Tags: probability, integration, random-variables, normal-distribution

let $X$ be normal random variable with $P(X>15)=0.75$ and $\sigma^{2}=4$. find $\mu$

**MY WORKING:**

Now I am using $pdf$  of normal random variable with $\sigma=2$ and $P(X>15)=0.75$ after plugging these values I get the following expression:

$$0.75=\int_{15}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{8}(x-\mu)^2} \,dx= \left.-\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{8}(x-\mu)^2} \frac{1}{4}(x-\mu)\right|_{15}^\infty$$

Now from here when I evaluate the limit I get the expression $0\times\infty$ in the first term. What should I do next? Is there a mistake. Kindly guide me.

Comment: You can't do the integral explicitly like that, you need to use software or a table. (Strictly speaking you can do it using a function called the error function or the complementary error function, but they're just defined in terms of this type of integral anyway so it doesn't really save you any trouble except maybe in setting up an implementation in software.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but the issue is this question is given to me as a practice. How am I suppose to use software which we haven't used in our class. There has to be other way.

Comment: Most likely you need to use a table of z scores, then.

Comment: You can just use a table like this one: https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/files/2013/10/Capture-d%E2%80%99e%CC%81cran-2013-10-15-a%CC%80-14.22.40.png

Comment: The table I linked to above says $\Pr(Z<0.67)$ is a little bit less than $0.75$ and $\Pr(Z<0.68)$ is a little bit more. That implies $\Pr(Z>-0.67)$ is a little bit less than $0.75$ and $\Pr(Z>-0.68)$ is a little bit more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
0.75 = {} & \Pr( X>15) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr\left( \frac{X-\mu} \sigma > \frac{15-\mu} 2 \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \Pr\left( Z> \frac{15-\mu} 2 \right)
\end{align}
The question now is: For what value of $z$ is $\Pr(Z>z)$ equal to $0.75$? This is the inverse of the standard normal cdf evaluated at $1-0.75.$ Standard software tells me this is $-0.6744898$ (rounded, of course). Thus we have
$$
\frac{15-\mu} 2 = -0.6744898
$$
This is to be solved for $\mu.$

If you have no suitable software you can use this table: https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/files/2013/10/Capture-d%E2%80%99e%CC%81cran-2013-10-15-a%CC%80-14.22.40.png

This table says $\Pr(Z<0.67) \approx 0.7486$ and $\Pr(Z<0.68)\approx 0.7517.$ So the number you seek is between those. Naive linear interpolation ("naive" = not thinking about how those numbers were rounded) yields${}\approx0.6745161.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int e^{-\frac{1}{8}(x-\mu)^2}\mathrm dx\neq -\frac{1}{4}(x-\mu)e^{-a(x-\mu)^2}$$

To see this just take the derivative on both sides. We need to use the [complementary error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html),

$$\int_a^\infty e^{-b(x-\mu)^2}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi/b}}{2}\operatorname{erfc}(\sqrt{b}~(a-\mu))$$

It is related to the normal [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) simply by $\operatorname{erfc}(z)=1-\operatorname{erf}(z)$

To compute the complementary error function, you can simply go to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Erfc%5B1.2%5D). In our case we want to find a number $\mu$ such that $$\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{erfc}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}\left(15-\mu\right)\right)=0.75$$

To do this we can use any kind of root finding algorithm we wish. [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NSolve%5B%281%2F2%29*Erfc%5BSqrt%5B1%2F8%5D*%2815-x%29%5D%3D%3D0.75%2Cx%5D) finds
$$\mu\approx 16.349$$

Comment: Either your answer is more complicated than it needs to be or else the question was intended differently from the way I construed it. That second possibility is a real possibility.

Comment: (Besides, your answer is obviously wrong: $(15-1.47398)/\sigma = (15-1.47398)/2 > 6,$ i.e. your talking about the probability of being more than six standard deviations above the mean!! That is NOT $0.75$. And there's an obvious reason why $\mu$ must be more than $15. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for catching the error. I (rather stupidly I might add) used $a$ twice, confusing myself! I'll fix.

Comment: @MichaelHardy How is this answer any more complicated than yours? All you've done is brush the details I've given under the "software" rug.

Comment: For one thing, it's visually more complicated, making it look as if one will have to think about integrals when it is almost certain that what was intended was that tables will be used.